# Display custom columns in HANA Query

Tags: hana

I would like to know if there is a HANA/SQL query that can change the below data:

```
U_User  U_Calendar
John    Calendar 1
James   Calendar 3
Mike    Calendar 1
Carol   Calendar 1
Jethro  Calendar 2
Harry   Calendar 2
```

into something like this?

```
Calendar 1  Calendar 2  Calendar 3
John        Jethro      James
Mike        Harry   
Carol
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: do you have a limit on the number of calendars?  Normally a Pivot would work (assuming static number of columns or a dynamic SQL if not static) or a case statement if pivot is unsupported.  2 second query http://scn.sap.com/thread/3527126

Comment: No, there's no limit. the amount of calendars can also vary each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For up to SPS 11, SAP HANA doesn't provide a PIVOT command on SQL level. Unconfirmed [comments](https://scn.sap.com/message/16045557#16045557) say that the command is already in the backlog but not yet scheduled for any release.

This article summarizes alternatives for PIVOT: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3527126

If you have **exactly** 3 calendars then you can get away with a static SQL script but for a dynamic number of calendars, you have to use dynamic SQL. The link above also has examples for both, but it gets messy really fast.

Comment: this looks like the best way to do it as far as I've seen but like you said gets messy because the number of calendars is never fixed.